# Как сделать так,чтобы виджет (Label в tkinter) двигался при нажатие на кнопку (Button)?

Tags: python, tkinter

Вот например у нас код:

```
from tkinter import *
def click():
    # дальше, я не знаю
k = Label(text="текст", fg="red",bg="black")
b = Button(text="click", command=click, fg = 'red', bg='green')
k.place(x=50, y=50)
b.place(x=100, y = 100)
```

Как сделать ,чтобы при нажатие на кнопку click виджет виджет "текст" двигался на 10 пикселей(при каждом нажатие)?

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит пытаться динамически изменять расположение виджетов `tkinter`, ипользуйте для этого *Canvas*. Вот пример с перемещением текста:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
text = canvas.create_text(250, 50, fill="green", text="VVVVVVVVV")


def move():
    canvas.move(text, 0, 10)
    canvas.update()


button = tk.Button(text='move', command=move)
button.pack(side='bottom', padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```