# Как изменить позицию всех виджетов класса Label?

Tags: python, ооп, функции, tkinter, виджет

Интересует вопрос, как изменить координаты (place(x, y)) всех динамически созданных текстовых виджетов на экране, при нажатии на кнопку?
Имеются десятки виджетов **одного класса** и нужно изменить координаты (или позицию) всех виджетов этого класса по оси "y". Например, координаты этих виджетов должны меняться на y+=10 при нажатии на какую-нибудь кнопку.

Comment: Поместите их в один фрейм, фрейм разместите через place. Потом фрейм целиком перемещайте. Ну или добавляйте их в какой-то список при создании, потом проходя по этому списку перемещайте каждый его элемент.

Comment: Смотрите <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278400/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-label-%D0%B2-tkinter-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-b>. Всем объектам text, присвойте один тэг, допустим tag="ttt" , и изменяйте наздоровье.

Comment: @inscolor Спасибо версия с фреймом и так понятна. Но мне в дальнейшем нужна будет перемещать не 10 виджетов, а к примеру 5 из них по этому координату.

Comment: @Сергей Версия с тегами мне не знакома. Можете по подробнее?

Comment: Виджеты созданы используя цикла таким образом Label(root, text=f'WWW {i}'). Интересна как я могу получить доступ к каждому экземпляру этого класса? Если объявить их всех каким-то именем, то изменения выполняются только над последним.

Comment: Виджеты создаются столько, сколько элементов имеются в базе данных. Поэтому выбрал решение создать их динамически вышепоказанным образом. Если знаете другого варианта, поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: про теги и анимацию, можно почитать <https://younglinux.info/tkinter/canvasmeth>

Comment: @walker025 вот в цикле не просто создавайте их, а добавляйте в список.